# Concerns about connecting to MySQL database to jupyter notebook

Tags: mysql, jupyter-notebook

I have been trying to connect my MySQL database to Jupiter notebook. Could anyone take a look at it and maybe provide some feedback or improvements I could do? As connecting to a database is a first for me, and I would like to know if there is anything I could do to make it better

```
engine = db.create_engine("mysql+mysqlconnector://user:password@hostname/database")

df = pd.read_sql_query("select * from customer", engine) 

engine.dispose()

df
```

Any feedback is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Install packages in CMD:

```
pip3 install mysqlclient
pip3 install pymysql
pip3 install ipython-sql
```

In the jupyter notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql


connection=pymysql.connect(host='localhost',port=int(3306),user='root',password='PASSWORD',db='DBNAME')

df=pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM 'TABLENAME' ",connection)

print(df)
```

Refer this [article](https://medium.com/@smohajer85/mysql-on-jupyter-fa89943f645d) by Saeed Mohajeryami

Comment: Do I need to close the connection afterwards? Thank you for your comment

Comment: Yes you can, but not necessary.